# First split the string and then separate character using substring

Tags: c#, autocad

`D:\Ajay\Autocad\534-W1A-R1.dwg` is my string and I want to split it and separate using split and substring so that I get character `1` and `A` separately for print.

Comment: Split based on what ? and what is the substring ? You have multiple 1's. Please be more specific.

Comment: split based on '\'.and i want '1' which is in between W and A

Comment: So you want 1 only or 1 and A ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Split to get the fileName, you can do this:

```
var result = str.Split('\\').Last()                     
                .Split('-').ElementAt(1).Skip(1);

char first = result.ElementAt(0);
char second = result.ElementAt(1);

Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.WriteLine(second);
```

Prints:

```
1
A
```

Comment: The word  ' W ' is not same i mean in different file the word is changed so what can i do for that?

Comment: @Ajjags So what is the pattern ? Get the second word in the split of `-` ? You need to have clear requirements.

Comment: @Ajjags So do you want the last two characters of the first word after the first `-` in the file name ?

Comment: I want both values seprate so i can  print both value individually

Comment: @Ajjags They can be separated , but how do you identify which characters ? Last two characters in the first word after the first `-` ?

Comment: 534-W1A-R1 in given file name W is the only word which changes according to sheet like 'C', 'S', 'D', 'W', 'M'

Comment: I want to print that 1 and A seprately like 1 is phase and A is zone value.

Comment: @Ajjags please mark this as the accepted answer if you find it helpful. Like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235